# Iterating list of list to populate json using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I would like to populate a json by iterating through a list of list with python.

Currently the list of list looks like this:

```
bookmark_apps = [['Google App','https://google.com'], ['Yahoo App','https://yahoo.com'], ['Espn App','https://espn.com']]
```

I would like to populate the JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": **Populate App Name Here**,
  "label": **Populate App Name Here**,
  "signOnMode": "BOOKMARK",
  "settings": {
    "app": {
      "requestIntegration": false,
      "url": **Populate App URL Here**
    }
  }
}
```

Im confident that there is a better way to approach it then way I'm trying. The way I tried approaching this was breaking it down within 2 lists and iterating through that with zip like this:

```
app_name_label = []
for sub_list in bookmark_apps:
    app_name_label.append(sub_list[0])

bookmark_url = []
for sub_list2 in bookmark_apps:
    bookmark_url.append(sub_list2[1])

for i, j in zip(name_label, needed_bookmark_url):
```

Any suggestions or approaches to get to the solution of populating the json will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: does the `name` and `label` keys exist are do we have to create them?

Comment: @deadshot they dont exist - so it would be needed to create them

Comment: You don't need `zip`. Your code is equivalent to `for i, j in bookmark_apps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension that creates dictionaries from the nested lists.

```
result = [{
        "name": name,
        "label": name,
        "signOnMode": "BOOKMARK",
        "settings": {
            "app": {
                "requestIntegration": False,
                "url": url
            }
        }
    } for name, url in bookmark_apps]
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/J9OeXy)

Comment: This solution creates over dues it by putting the wrong "name" associated with the wrong "url". For example it will create me this

```
{
        "name": "Google App",
        "label": "Google App",
        "signOnMode": "BOOKMARK",
        "settings": {
            "app": {
                "requestIntegration": False,
                "url": "https://yahoo.com"
            }
        }
    }

Comment: just checked it out. Works - Thank you a lot for the help.

Comment: Do you know how can I iterate through "results" for each json body. This is so I can make the request via API. It seems that all the json body are concatenated within the list.

Comment: `for result in results:` then send a request using `result`.